# Leftmost bisect search to find valid perfect square

Tags: python, performance

I am working on [Valid Perfect Square - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-perfect-square/) 
and wrote a standard leftmost bisect search to solve the problem:

```
class Solution:
    def isPerfectSquare(self, num: int) -> bool:
        #base case 1
        if num == 1: return True 
        lo = 1
        hi = num
        #recur case 
        while lo < hi:
            mid = (lo + hi) // 2
            if num > mid ** 2:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid 
        return True if lo ** 2 == num else False
```

However, the score is annoying:

> Runtime: 48 ms, faster than 24.22% of Python3 online submissions for Valid Perfect Square.
>   Memory Usage: 13.2 MB, less than 5.17% of Python3 online submissions for Valid Perfect Square.

I am not able to improve a standard template a little bit.

Could you please provide any advice?

Comment: It doesn't justify an answer imo, but python has builtin bisect which would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small points:

## ternary expression

No need for `return True if lo ** 2 == num else False`. you can use just `return lo ** 2 == num`

## early return

If `mid**2 == num`, you can return early:

```
sq = mid ** 2
if num == sq:
    return True
if num > sq:
    lo = mid + 1
else:
    hi = mid -1
```

returns early in this case. This reduced the time for me to 36ms.

## unpacking

If you want, you can use a ternary expression and tuple unpacking to redefine `hi` and `lo`

```
lo, hi = (mid + 1, hi) if num > sq else (lo, mid - 1)
```

but this is a matter of taste, and doesn't seem to save any time or memory.

## memory

I don't see a lot of ways in which to reduce this method's memory usage. If you look at the distribution of all [submissions](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/221922019/), almost all use this bisect method, so memoty reduction will be based on the wims of the VM.